# Conversion between Time Zone gives incorrect results

Tags: java, datetime, time, jodatime

```
 DateTime dt = new LocalDateTime(rs.getTimestamp("LastUpdated").getTime()).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")); 

Timestamp t=new Timestamp(dt.getMillis());
```

The result I get from this doesn't match the actual Time of the "America/New_York". It is off by several hours. What could possibly be the problem?

Update-

This is the Time I want to convert which is from the DB: 2015-04-28 13:14:31 This is the converted Time(output of the code after removing "dt.plusMillis(offset)" from the code: 2015-04-28 22:44:31.0 This was the actual NY time :3:45 AM

Comment: Can you give some expected and actual outputs? It is unclear to me why you are adding an offset to the millis.

Comment: I just removed adding the offset. This is the result after removing the adding the offset.

This is the Time I want to convert which is from the DB:  2015-04-28 13:14:31

This is the converted Time(output of the code after removing "dt.plusMillis(offset)" from the code: 2015-04-28 22:44:31.0

This was the actual NY time :3:45 AM

Comment: Please provide this information by editing the question, rather than hiding it in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to make it with JODA library. Core java libraries are painfull and they are not suggested to use. However, Date and Time libraries has been reimplemented with Java 8.

Lets make an example, assume that you try to convert Melbourne Australia time to Madrid time.

Here is the Joda code;

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = new LocalDateTime(2015, 3, 28, 14, 0, 0); 
    DateTime srcDateTime = dateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Colombo"));
    DateTime dstDateTime = srcDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
    Date madridTime =dstDateTime.toLocalDateTime().toDateTime().toDate();


    System.out.println("Asia/Colombo -> "+srcDateTime.toDateTime());
    System.out.println("America/New_York -> "+madridTime);
```

Here is the output:

```
Asia/Colombo -> 2015-04-28T14:00:00.050+05:30
America/New_York -> Tue Apr 28 04:30:00 EEST 2015
```

You can also check from http://www.timezoneconverter.com/

[image]

**See Also:**

[Date and Time API for JDK 8](http://geekmonkey.org/articles/24-a-new-date-and-time-api-for-jdk-8)

Comment: No need to bring `Calendar` into it, you should use `new LocalDateTime(2015, 5, 13, 20, 0, 0)` as this does not depend upon the jvm default timezone.

Comment: @AndyTurner You are rigth. I edited the answer. thanks.

Comment: I still do not get the correct converted time.  Get a different result. Could it be something to do with daylight saving?

Comment: what are the time zones are you tring to convert ? @TheShadow123

Comment: Src time is ="Asia/Colombo" and Dst="America/New_York"

Comment: This works correct for me. see my edits @TheShadow123

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
myResultSet
.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class )   // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object represent a moment as seen through some offset-from-UTC, a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind UTC. 
.atZoneSameInstant(                      // Adjusts from a moment with a mere offset to a moment as seen in a time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" )
)
```

## *Joda-Time* in maintenance mode

FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## `LocalDateTime` is not a moment

The `LocalDateTime` class (in both Joda-Time & *java.time*) does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. This class is not usually used in business apps except for (a) booking appointments in the future, and (b) representing a date with time-of-day that could apply to *any* place but not a specific place.

## Avoid `java.sql.Timestamp`

Apparently you are retrieved a `java.sql.Timestamp` object from a `ResultSet`. Stop doing this.

### `OffsetDateTime`

This terrible class was replaced years ago by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) when used with [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 and later.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

To see this [moment in the New York](https://time.is/New_York) region’s time zone, apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

**Same moment**, same simultaneous point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

Be clear on the difference between offset and zone:

- [**Offset-from-UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)
  Simply a number of hours-minutes-seconds. Positive for being ahead of UTC (towards the east) and negative for being behind UTC (towards the west).
- [**Time zone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone)
  A time zone is *much* more. A time zone is a history of the past, present, and future (planned) changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).